# Unable to process 1.3gb PDF file by iText

Tags: java, file, pdf, itext

I am currently using iText 2.1.7 to modify an existing PDF file of size 1.3gb, which fails to get processed producing java heap space error. The error is encountered while executing following line of code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Files.readAllBytes((new File(filenameSource)).toPath()));
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Start by not slurping the entire PDF into RAM. At a minimum, pass an `InputStream`; ideally, use a `FileChannel` with `RandomAccessSource` (available only in 5.3.5+).

Comment: Also note that older versions of iText (5.3 and older) can't handle files larger than ~2 GB. Newer versions can go up to ~1 TB. With 1.3 GB you are still below that limit but if you're already talking gigabyte files, it's good to keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since, I am using 2.1.7, I cant use FileChannel. Is there other way to resolve this issue?